# How exclude an entity and its properties in Entity Framework Migrations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

Consider I have this model:

```
// In Accounting.dll
public class Invoice
{
    public int Number{ get; set; }
    public Company { get; set; }
}

public AccountingDbContext : DbContext
{
    // ...

    public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}
```

In this model I've used `Company` which is defined in another project

```
// In Infrastructure.dll
public class Company
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }

}

public InfrastructureDbContext : DbContext
{
    // ...

    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

The `Company` is being created via `Infrastructure` Migrations. But in the `Accounting` project, it also finds the Company as something new to create a table for.

**Question:** How can I set migrations in `Accounting` to leave `Company` alone while scaffolding the migrations?

I've tried `modelBuilder.Entity<Company>.Ignore()`. It's not a good solution as the whole entity framework ignores it. I just want the migrations to ignore it.

Comment: You can just edit the migration so that it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @BenRobinson editing migration works but it's error-prone. What if someone adds a `Description` property to company? Again I should edit the generated migration to remove the `AddColumn("Description")` part.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue other than manually removing the duplicate `migrationBuilder.CreateTable()` from your Accouting.dll migration?

Comment: @RandyDaddis No didn't find a proper solution. But I found that the migration mechanism in EF Core is much more flexible for this problem.